# intente crear un array en js y luego envíela al controlador

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Estoy intentado de crear un `array` en JS para luego enviarlo a mi controlador en Codeigniter.

Tengo el siguiente problema la linea se me repite.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mi archivo JS.

```
function get_array(){
       var datos = [];
       row = {};
      $("#tbl_esctructura tbody > tr").each(function() {
        var item = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
         row["item"] = item;
         row["cantidad"] = cantidad;
         datos.push(row); // you push it to the array
      });

        datos =  JSON.stringify(datos);
    }
```

Mi controlador PHP

```
  public function data_from_array(){
        $data   =  array($this->input->post('datos', TRUE));
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            echo $row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que salida esperas?

Comment: @VickMuñoz item 1 cantidad 45, item 2 cantidad 45, item 3 cantidad 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario crear el objeto "row", lo puedes hacer directamente:

```
function get_array(){
    var datos = [];

    $("#tbl_esctructura tbody > tr").each(function() {
        var item = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();

        datos.push({
           "item": item,
           "cantidad": cantidad
        }); // you push it to the array
    });

    datos =  JSON.stringify(datos);

    return datos;
}
```

En tu Controlador vas a recibir un string que tienes que convertirlo a array con `json_decode` para poder usarlo

```
  public function data_from_array(){
        $data = $this->input->post('datos', TRUE);
        $array = json_decode($data);
        foreach ($array as $row) {
            echo $row->item;
            echo $row->cantidad;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Y en el ajax para mi controlador como debería recorrerlo?

Comment: Puedes hacer un `var_dump($data)` a tu variable para ver como está formado.

Comment: Esto me tira `string(57) "[{"item":"1","cantidad":"2"},{"item":"2","cantidad":"4"}]" `

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta para que veas como lo debes usar.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion

```
function get_array(){
       var datos = [];

      $("#tbl_esctructura tbody > tr").each(function() {
        var row = {};
        var item = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
         row["item"] = item;
         row["cantidad"] = cantidad;
         datos.push(row); // you push it to the array
      });

        datos =  JSON.stringify(datos);
    }
```